# Log<TState> never called on custom ILogger/ILogProvider implementation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I have implemented a custom logging system and everything seems to be working as expected, however, the `Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)` is never being called on my custom `ILogger` implementation.

I have been following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) and I have gone back through the guide about 20 times at this point and cannot seem to find anything that would cause this method to not be called. I have also gone through the source code for the built-in .NET Console logger but everything seems to line up with what I already have implemented.

I have traced through my code with breakpoints and my custom `ILoggerProvider` is being called. It is executing the `CreateLogger` method on my custom provider multiple times as I would expect. It is also calling the `IsEnabled` method a single time on my `ILogger` (which is implemented as `public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;` for testing). However, it is never calling the `Log<TState>` method on my `ILogger` even though I have a breakpoint on the following line and that breakpoint is in fact being hit.

`_logger.LogInformation("Running health check");` where `_logger` is a DI reference to `ILogger<HealthCheckMasterDatabase> logger`.

Is there a "gotcha" about implementing a custom logging system that I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Meet the same error, may due to the logger filter in configuration.

Solution:

(1) you can remove the following config "Logging" in appsettings.xx.json

(2) or, not remove it, add a new item in "LogLevel" for your custom logger provider.

[image]